# Background repeat not working on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, background

i've got little problem with my CSS, and HTML on mobile devices.
Image is not displayed in any way - tested on Samsung Galaxy S3.
I've got something like this:

```
.wlLeft, .wlRight {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
}

.wlLeft {
  background: url('../images/wlLeft.jpg') repeat;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: auto 100%;
  -moz-background-size: auto 100%;
  -o-background-size: auto 100%;
}

.wlRight {
  background: url('../images/wlRight.jpg') repeat;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: auto 100%;
  -moz-background-size: auto 100%;
  -o-background-size: auto 100%;
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<div class="wlLeft"></div>
<div class="wlRight"></div>
<div class="one page">
  <div class="inner2 left3">
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="przeszczep1" style="XHTML" />
  </div>
  <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you create a Fiddle for that?

Comment: Sure, here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/ppy9o5oL/

Answer (score 0):

If the idea is for the background to repeat on the div, isn't best to remove the background size with a media query on the mobile? then the image would actually repeat

Comment: yes, but it has to work with image, that have same background-size property